# tabula_py issue How to extract pdf table data spread in multiple pages

Tags: python, pypdf, tabula-py

I am trying to extract all tables data from a pdf using tabula_py as:
df=tabula.read_ptabula.read_pdf(test_pdf,stream=True,multiple tables=True,pages="all")

The pdf has 3 tables. Second table is on 2 pages.
 When I try len(df)  , it returns 4 instead of 3
The frist row on second table data on the extended page returns as header
How to extract the data as same table from the header to the last row

Comment: hello. did you find a solution?

Comment: was there a solution to this?